# Nginx allow download if initiated from my site

Tags: nginx

I have a simple link on a page that downloads a zipped folder that is in a directory. The anchor is really simple:

`<a href="https://example.com/downloads/private.zip" class="btn btn-success" type="button">Download Zip</a>`

It's on a page that requires the user be logged in but I'd still like to protect the downloads folder from being directly accessed in the browser. I got this idea from [this post](https://serverfault.com/questions/834252/nginx-allow-access-to-folder-directory-only-by-referring-url). It appears it is working to keep the zip from being directly downloaded but is causing a 404 when trying to download from from page it should work on.

```
   location /downloads/ {
       valid_referers *.example.com/download.php;
        if ($invalid_referer) {
            return 404;
        }      
   }
```

Also, how would I allow download from `/download` OR `/download.php`?

Posted this on ServerFault first but got no response.

Comment: Is your Nginx install built with the auth request module? You can run this to find out `nginx -V 2>&1 | grep -qF -- --with-http_auth_request_module && echo ":)" || echo ":("`

Comment: Yes it is. That echoed :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [auth_request](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_auth_request_module.html) module in Nginx to limit access based upon the response code returned to an internal subrequest.

You can pass the value of a cookie, the remote IP, a request header, whatever. You then have Nginx make a subrequest with this value to a script on your server which evaluates the value and returns an HTTP response code of 200 to allow access to the protected resource, or any other response code to deny it.

An example code block would look something like this:

```
location /downloads/ {
    auth_request /auth;
    ...
}

location = /auth {
    proxy_pass ...
    proxy_pass_request_body off;
    proxy_set_header Content-Length "";
    proxy_set_header X-Real-Ip $remote_addr;
}
```